# Configure Ubuntu VPS to send outgoing mail?

Tags: wordpress, apache, email, ubuntu, vps

I need to send mails from my VPS hosting a wordpress website, the outgoing mails are mainly for new users registrations and I cant find a sigle guide out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide to setup email service on Ubuntu if your VPS doesn't have it

http://jonsview.com/how-to-setup-email-services-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-tlssasl-and-dovecot

But usually if your VPS have Control panel like Plesk,cPanel ..etc... Just simple create a new email account and using it

You can also install this plugin to wordpress (optional). If you want send mail via SMTP 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: http://jonsview.com/how-to-setup-email-services-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-tlssasl-and-dovecot
Worked great, thank you very much!